# AJAX call not working - PHP, MySQL, jQuery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following problem:

What i'm trying to accomplish is:

- User clicks on a submit/image type button
- Ajax call handles the submit, calls another PHP script to update a record in a MySQL table, all without reloading the page ( obviously )

My PHP code is working fine without the AJAX, as it will reload and update the record. but somehow the ajax call is not working and/or returning any error.

My code:

```js
 $(function() {

$('#like_form').submit(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); // Preventing default submit button

    var formEl = $('#like_form');
    var submitButton = $('input[type=submit]', formEl);

    $.ajax({
   async: true, 
      type: 'POST',
      url: formEl.prop('action'),
      accept: {
        javascript: 'application/javascript'
      },
 
      beforeSend: function() {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    }).done(function(data) {
      submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
    $("#like").fadeOut();
    $("#like").fadeIn();
   
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- LIKE een gebruiker -->
   <form action="" id="like_form" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input onmouseover="this.src='img/heart2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/heart.png'" name='like' id="like" src='img/heart.png' type="image" />
   </form>
```

my PHP (just in case):

```html
<?php
include_once "dbconnection.php";

//if like button (submit button) clicked
if ($_POST){
$conn = DatabaseConnection::getConnection();
$sql = "UPDATE dating_members
SET likes = likes + 1
WHERE member_id = 3";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
}

?>
```

Comment: have you made sure your request works with postman?

Comment: I don't have any data to be posted. All i'm trying to reach is once the submit button is clicked, to fire the PHP script to update ( increment) a value in the mysql table. the submit button is the only form element in my form. no other inputs are required.

Comment: why would you have a post with no data? Defeats the purpose of using post method. What is status of request? You say you see no error but you don't have any ajax erro handling

Comment: it will have a hidden input field in the future that will $_GET the users id and post it my PHP script, for now, I have hard-coded the ID just to test the function, but there is something with the AJAX call as without it, everything works just fine.

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but the submitButton uses the selector `'input[type=submit]'` but the type in the HTML is given as `type="image"`.

Comment: it works for both image and submit, Have tried it with my other codes with ajax calls and works as they are pretty much the same.

Comment: When you say you're ajax call is not working, do you mean the request isn't sent at all? Does the `beforeSend` callback get executed? Does the `done` callback get executed? Does the `#like_form` submit handler even get called? You need to determine where  in your code things are failing.

Comment: Yes, beforeSend gets executed and so does the #like_form submit handler. I have the exact same scripts for another project which works like a charm, but this one doesn't. the only difference with now is that it's not passing any data, but Like I said.. it's not required to pass any data ( yet ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is, Kind of silly I didn't notice but better late than never.

I had to 'include' the JS script at the end of my PHP page in order to  catch my onsubmit function and therefore disable the default event a.k.a submit button submitting my form and page reload / POSTs to the other PHP file.

Everything is working fine now